# how can i export the mysql-promise as a module in node Js?

Tags: mysql, node.js, postgresql

Here I have a simple config file for a postgres db:

**postresql.config.js**

```
const pg = require('pg-promise')()

const connectionString = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8080,
    database: 'test',
    user: 'test',
    password: 'test123678!'
}

let db = pg(connectionString);

module.exports = {
    db
}
```

This file is used in the DataAccess file to do some query, like this:

```
let db = require('../configs/postgresql.config').db;

let getAll = function() {
    return db.manyOrNone('my query')
        .then(function (res) {
            console.log(res);
            return res;
        });
};
```

Using the pg-promise module is very fast and easy. 
But i get in trouble when i try to do the samething with a mysql database.
How can I achieve the same result with the promise-mysql module?

Comment: "How can I achieve the same result with the promise-mysql module?" What have you tried so far? What was the problem?

Comment: I've removed the promise anti-pattern from the example. No need for creating extra promises there, it does nothing useful.

Comment: Rsp, i tryed the mysql-promise package but i can't get to work.

Comment: vitaly-t can you explain why? i'm still learning node.js

Comment: @MattiaPettenuzzo See [The Forgotten Promise](http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/#the-forgotten-promise:8f173b15e2d19515fdc8ce931ae539c0)

Answer (score 0):

Use something universal, pg-promise is exclusive for PostgreSQL database.
There is this awesome called bluebird , which can be integrated into any instance of a function.http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: also it can promisify any function making asynchronous in nature.